# How to turn two android apps into 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Before I joined the company the developers had our application split into 2.

```
library project with all the code
xxx.xxx.app.library

xxx.xxx.app
xxx.xxx.app.amazon
```

As you can probably tell one is for google play and the other is for Amazon's app store and both of these are really just shell apps because the library one has all the code.

So with that we have 4 build.gradle files.  The top level, lib, app, and app.amazon.

Is there any way I can get rid of the library and amazon directories and just have the play directory (moving all the lib code there of course) and have gradle make the 2 apks (1 for amazon and 1 for play)?

Answer (score 2):

The AndroidStudio solution for that is Flavours. You can have the general app and define two flavours for Amazon and Google Play. In each Flavour you can have Classes, resources, etc. which are different from the default.

In the gradle file you can define the package name and configuration for each of the flavours.

No need for a library in this configuration.

Comment: How could I handle the fact that we are using GCM and you have to have a separate androidmanifest.xml and google-services.json?

Comment: you can even have two android manifests, one default and one for the flavour(s). then the GCM can be in one or several classes that handle the libraries. Again for the embedded libraries each flavour has its own gradle-definition. start with Bobby Hargetts link. Flavours are really great and worth checking out